# 2000 Honda Civic SiR turbo sputter and stalling

Tags: honda, civic, turbocharger

To start I have a lot of deletes and tuned ecu on a B18 bottom end with B16 top. Turbo has been set to cut out at 5psi on the ecu. 
I have a good feeling it is something fuel as I am having problems keeping any pressure in the fuel lines to keep it running. I have powered the pump alone and it works. I put my fuel pump relay in a friends car and it works. Brand new fuel filter, fuel pressure gauge attached. it now won't even start.
What could be going on??

Comment: So what does the fuel pressure gauge read while cranking?

Comment: How did you power the pump? Did you jump the relay terminals? What's fuel pressure? How about fuses? Voltage drop?

Comment: List your deletes.